# How to divide the values of multiple columns by the values of a single column of a dataset in R

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a dataset similar to the following that I am showing you

| gene_name | gene_length | value1 | value2 | value3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NameA | 1070 | 100 | 300 | 600 |
| NameB | 110 | 200 | 600 | 1200 |

My goal is to **create new columns with the results of the division** of the **values that are in the columns value1, value2, value3.... value-n** by the **values that are in the gene_length column**.

Something like this:

| gene_name | gene_length | value1 | value2 | value3 | value1_result | value2_result | value3_result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NameA | 1070 | 100 | 300 | 600 | 0.0934 | 0.2803 | 0.5607 |
| NameB | 110 | 200 | 600 | 1200 | 1.8181 | 5.4545 | 10.9090 |

I could apply several mutate functions in R with few columns and rows, but the problem is that **my dataset has more than 50 thousand rows and 21 columns.**

**How could this task be accomplished using the tidyverse more efficiently?**

I have read that I could use the mutate function in conjunction with the across function, however I have not been able to get them to work together.

```
desired_df <- df %>% 
  mutate(across(.cols = 3:21, # 21 because of the 21 columns i have in my dataframe
                # I need to specify a function to perform the division in the columns i want 
                # but i dont know how
                .names = '{col}_value')) # names of new columns
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop `across` the 'value' columns, create a lambda function (`~`) to divide the column (`.x`) by the 'gene_length' and modify the `.names` to create new columns with `_result` as suffix

```
library(dplyr)
desired_df <- df %>% 
  mutate(across(.cols = starts_with("value"), ~ .x/gene_length,
                .names = '{.col}_result'))
```

-output

```
> desired_df
  gene_name gene_length value1 value2 value3 value1_result value2_result value3_result
1     NameA        1070    100    300    600    0.09345794     0.2803738     0.5607477
2     NameB         110    200    600   1200    1.81818182     5.4545455    10.9090909
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
 nm1 <- grep("value", names(df), value = TRUE)
 setDT(df)[, paste0(nm1, "_result") := lapply(.SD, \(x) 
       x/gene_length), .SDcols = nm1]
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(gene_name = c("NameA", "NameB"), gene_length = c(1070L, 
110L), value1 = c(100L, 200L), value2 = c(300L, 600L), value3 = c(600L, 
1200L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Comment: It worked perfectly, I was missing this part:

  ~ .x/gene_length

thanks for the help! :)